# Getting error while passing input value as 1525 to oracle procedure using SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am calling oracle stored procedure via SimpleJdbcCall, the script is mentioned below **throws error(ORA-01722:) when passing 1525 as parameter value**

```
 SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
    .addValue("param1","1")
    .addValue("param2","1525");
    
    Map<String, Object> result= simpleJdbcCall.execute(param);

CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call XYZ(?,?)}]; ORA-01722: invalid number;
```

when i pass param2 as some other value say example "1525a" it not throwing error.

is there any restriction to pass 1525 as parameter value?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stacktrace of the exception you get.

Comment: Try to execute the oracle stored procedure xyz, in plsql developer or toad or any developer tool, by passing the same value ("1", "1525") and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you problem is with Stored procedure. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If procedure expect a number, send a number and not a String:

```
 SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource()
.addValue("param1","1")
.addValue("param2", 1525);
```

Comment: Tried changing to Number, But still the same error org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback

Comment: @BibinRaj probably different issue of re-entering same duplicate data

Comment: Parameter is setting single time only : Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call XYZ(?, ?)}]; ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Thank you for your comments. problem with the stored proc